# Magento 2: display registration/sign in screen before checkout ONLY if specific SKU exists in basket

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer-account, registration

We have a project where in most cases we want checkout to be guest only

However, if there is a particular SKU in the cart we want the registration/sign in box to be presented when they click through from cart to checkout

At present, if we disable guest checkout, this happens for everyone

I've seen extensions out there for conditional registration, but these all seem to be around accessing specific pages and not based on the contents of the cart

Does anyone have any ideas / resources they can point me to that would help with this?

Comment: i'm pretty disappointed while you gave my answer correct after bounty expired.

Comment: It shows +50 next to the answer to me? Bounty expires in 2 hours, so if I've done something wrong please let me know and I'll fix...  Thanks for your answer - I've been away so haven't been able to test yet, but will ask for clarification if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem you have to use the observer **checkout_allow_guest**.

Make sure the checkout as guest is allowed: **Yes**

Here we prevent guest customers base on cart sku.

`etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_allow_guest">
        <observer name="checkout_allow_guest" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\IsAllowedGuestCheckoutObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

`Observer/IsAllowedGuestCheckoutObserver.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;

class IsAllowedGuestCheckoutObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Check is allowed guest checkout if quote contain any matched sku product(s)
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();

        /* @var $quote Quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            /** @var Product $product */
            $product = $item->getProduct();

            if ($product->getSku() === 'foobar') {
                $result->setIsAllowed(false);
                break;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index** event for this. In this observer event, you can check your custom condition of cart item SKU and then redirect the page. Check the below code for reference:

> Create **events.xml** file at path:
> `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework/Event/etc/events.xsd'>
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index">
            <observer name="customer_controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index _event" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckoutPreloadObserver" disabled="false" />
        </event> 
</config>
```

> Create **CheckoutPreloadObserver.php** file at path:
> `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CheckoutPreloadObserver.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckoutPreloadObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Your custom code here for check cart items and redirect.
    }
}
```